# flink impala jdbc insert is slow

Tags: jdbc, apache-flink, impala

currently we're facing some performance issue for *flink* job using **jdbc** to **insert** around 1 millions data per hour to Kudu table using impala jdbc.

we've tried to increase the parameters

```
JdbcExecutionOptions.builder()
    .withBatchSize(1000)
    .withBatchIntervalMs(200)
    .withMaxRetries(3)
    .build()
```

with checkpoint interval 10 second and checkpoint timeout 10 minute with no result.
we also try to increase the parallel from 3 to 6, but also not working.

we also try to increase the BatchSize to 10000 but we are facing error

```
org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.JdbcBatchingOutputFormat [] - JDBC executeBatch error, retry times = 0
java.sql.SQLException: [Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AnalysisException: Exceeded the statement exp
ression limit (250000)
Statement has 720000 expressions.
```

the best we could get is 1500 records / minute, with parameters of

```
JdbcExecutionOptions.builder()
    .withBatchSize(200)
    .withBatchIntervalMs(50)
    .withMaxRetries(3)
    .build()
```

and checkpoint interval 3 second and checkpoint timeout 10 minute.

Is there any others parameters that we could use to get better performance of this case ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact config flink, so please provide full details. The most common error is due to lack of *rewriteBatchedStatements=true* in URL. That's because JDBC will send 1000 single insert statements instead of 1 consisting of 1000 insert statements.

Comment: Hi Viet, 

as we seen on the flink logs, it seem flink by default already sent single insert query.
if we try to set parameter for Batch Size too big it will give error

`errorMessage:AnalysisException: Exceeded the statement exp
ression limit (250000)`

we are running flink on 3 server with 64cpu and 320gb allocated from yarn pool.

Comment: Like I said, even though flink buffered and batched your queries and sent them down to the DB, the DB didn't realize it had to batch, so your DB must have an indication from Flink something like that like this: url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?rewriteBatchedStatements = true.

"Exceeded the statement expression limit (250000) Statement has 720000 expressions." => This means each of your single statements is executing too many expressions, it's too long...Example: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ... IN (~250000 value)...